# Whereas vs While

Tags: grammar

In the following text is it also correct to use while instead of whereas?:

> The start of a romance with the much older Padmé Amidala (played by Natalie Portman) was difficult to believe, as Lloyd was only 10 years old when the movie was released, ***whereas*** Portman was 18 years old.

Are these two words interchangeable?

Comment: useful - http://marisateachesenglish.blogspot.in/2013/02/difference-between-while-and-whereas.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in your context they are interchangeable but this doesn’t happen always.

While is connected to temporality and can be used when we want to talk to things that happen simultaneously. In this sense it is similar to **as** or **when**.

**While** and **whereas** can be used interchangeably to link two ideas that contrast with each other.

**While** does not always refer to time. It is also used to balance two ideas that contrast with, but do not contradict, each other. In this sense, it is similar to **whereas**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this context, the sentence is written to contrast the ages of Lloyd and Portman. In that context, they are inter changeable and you will find this in a dictionary as the conjunctive usage of while mapping to whereas.